# Failing to retrieve li nodes in an html list

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-lists, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape an html document in order to get a value from a ul list with the following structure:

```
<ul id="indicators0" class="connectedIndicators ui-sortable">
  <li id="ind-speed" style="">speed=0.014774</li>
  <li id="ind-speed_01" style="display: list-item;"></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I can easily reach the node "indicators0" by following any of the numerous examples in the web using the Html Agility Pack:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@id='indicators0']");
```

However, any try to retrieve the li nodes fails to succeed. I'm trying stuff like the following:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode subNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@id='indicators0'] //li").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode subNode = node.Descendants("li").FirstOrDefault();
```

Which in both cases return null values. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Given this specific HTML markup as input, your code should've worked fine : https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Y4Q6A

Answer (score 0):

have you tried.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode subNode = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@id='indicators0']/li[1]");
```

When pulling out these values you are using xsl to map down to the node/nodes to find the item you are looking for, and just the first one.

in the first one, rightfully so, so are pulling the entire UL out of the html.

the other 2 I cannot see much of a problem with right now, apologies, I am quite tired.

If my suggestion doesn't work, have you debugged to find out what that node is that is coming back? it is possible you are lot hitting the right ul, OR is it possible you are looking for the LI, before they are *dynamically loaded*(I am not sure if you are loading anything dynamically, just an assumption made)

what you could also do if the id is always the same for the LI is this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode subNode = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li[@id='ind-speed']");
```

if this receives something, there is a good chance that you have more than one ul that first the description you are looking for in the scope of the htmlDoc

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very curious about stuff dynamically loaded since the html retrieve its data from an running online game. Those code snippets don't work for me since those are the usual routines.

Comment: Apparently the html is generated by javascript, which fits the category of "dynamically loaded" and I've to use a WebBrowser object. You got me in the right path!